# Method overloading alternatives java

Tags: java, overloading

I understand method overloading is a subset of the Polymorphism OOP feature.

I understand that a good practice would be to use method overloading concept if the purpose of a method is the same, but it might differ in the parameters intake.

One trivial example would be calculating a sum for 2,3 or more parameters.

```
public int caluclateSum(int a, int b){
  return a+b;
}

public int caluclateSum(int a, int b, int c){
  return a+b+c;
}
```

Questions:

1. Would there be a OOP programing pattern to use, for accomplishing the same result.
2. Can this be achieved through functional programming, Lambdas.

In which scenarios would that pattern would be more useful than method overloading, for both programing paradigms.

Comment: This question might be more suited for [cs.se].

Comment: For your example it looks like what method needs [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) `public int caluclateSum(int... numbers){
  int sum = 0; for (int n : numbers){sum+=n;} return sum;
}`. Usage `int result = caluclateSum(1,2,3,4,5);`

Answer (score 1):

As others already said, your given example would benefit from varargs. But that's just one example, and is completely outside of any OOP discussion.

In my view, overloading has nothing to do with OOP. It's just some independent methods that accidentally got the same name. Luckily, they have different parameter lists, so the compiler is able to guess which one you meant. Having instead methods with different names gives exactly the same results (and without the potential ambiguities introduced by overloading). It's just more reader-friendly to always see e.g. `sum(...)` instead of `sumIntInt(...)` or `sumIntIntInt(...)`.

On the other hand, OOP polymorphism means that the method to be used is decided at runtime, depending on the runtime type of some instance involved in the call. In Java, it's only the instance "before the dot" that gets that treatment. The various classes that can be passed into the call may each have their own implementation of the method, and that's called overriding.

So, whenever you want to make some behaviour dependent on some instance class, make it a method of the relevant class tree.

If you were to apply that pattern to your example, you'd e.g. have to create some (contrived) classes/interfaces:

- `SomeIntegers` as an interface with a method `sum()`,
- `TwoIntegers` implementing `SomeIntegers`, with fields `a` and `b` and a `sum()` method adding those two numbers,
- `ThreeIntegers` implementing `SomeIntegers`, with fields `a`, `b`, and `c` and a `sum()` method adding those three numbers.

Then you'd use code following the pattern:

```
SomeIntegers someInts = ...;
int result = someInts.sum();
```

Depending on the concrete class of the `someInts` instance, you'd get the appropriate addition implementation.

Of course, this is a quite contrived example, but maybe it helps to get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the input Ralf. My example was to start a conversation and hoping that would generate more complex examples, from which possible alternative patterns to cope with the overloading methods would emerge. 
For now I will let this oppen and maybe in time i will be able to provide an Edit.

Comment: @Scilla  That's not how Stackoverflow works. It's about specific questions with specific answers, not a general discussion forum.

Answer (score -1):

If you just need more of the same parameter, you probably wouldn't need to use Overloading.
There are [varargs](https://www.baeldung.com/java-varargs) for that purpose, something like that:

```java
public int caluclateSum(int... numbers) {
    return Arrays.stream(numbers).sum();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the first parameter is required you should create a method with signature

```
public int caluclateSum(int first, int... numbers) {
    ///......
}
```